How can I define multiple WHERE conditions?
I have an app backend based on laravel.
It has databases in mysql
I have the following code which retrieves, based on an API call from the app - a subset of category data based on user id.
public function get_categories()
    {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $categories = Category::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
        return $this->returnApiResponse(200, 'Categories fetched successfully', array('categories' => CategoryResource::collection($categories)));
    }

How do I adapt it so that it retrieves categories based on the matching user_id AND one that I specific e.g. user_id = 0
For example I have tried
$categories = Category::where('user_id', $user_id)->get() + Category::where('user_id', 0)->get();

and
$categories = Category::where('user_id', $user_id AND 0)->get()

But I am getting nowhere. I don't really understand the php syntax and querying database tables.
I want it to return the categories associated with the user logged into the app, AND a user_id that I specify.

You can add an additional "where" into your code:
$categories = Category::where('user_id', $user_id)->where('category_name', 'something')->get()


public function get_categories()
{
    $userId = auth()->user()->id; //Get user id.

    // Query for categories matching the logged-in user OR user_id = 0
    $categories = Category::where('user_id', $userId)
                          ->orWhere('user_id', 0)
                          ->get();

    return $this->returnApiResponse(
        200,
        'Categories fetched successfully',
        array('categories' => CategoryResource::collection($categories))
    );
}


Please add second WHERE:
$categories = Category::where('user_id', $user_id)
                      ->where('status', 1)
                      ->get();

In this code we use this code ->where('status', 1) as second where please modify according to your code
